# How would you simplify this expression involving complex numbers and a logarithm?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, absolute-value, potential-theory

The expression is

$$\log\left(\left| \frac{z+ia}{z-ia}\right|\right) $$

Here, $a>0$ is real, $i$ is the imaginary unit, and $z=x+iy$. The expression comes from extracting the imaginary part of an expression so it should end up being purely real, however I can't manage to remove the imaginary unit from any of my expressions. I know that it should end up being something like:

$$\frac{1}{2} \log\left( \frac{x^2 + (y+a)^2}{x^2 + (y-a)^2}\right)$$

Comment: What sort of simplification are you looking for. It clearly is real (unless $y=-a$) since the expression is $\geq 0$. But without more structure, this might be all you get

Comment: I want to reach the expression at the end of my question, in terms of $x$ and $y$ and no imaginary unit. I want to know how.

Comment: $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ since they describe the real and imaginary parts of $z$ respectively

Comment: Of course. I want to know how to get from my first expression to my second expression.

Comment: In the answer below you express confusion since "Your first line holds only if $x$ is real, no? In my case what you are treating like $x$ is in fact $z$, a complex number". I am saying that $x$ is in fact a real number. So what is your confusion with the answer then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that $|z|=|x+iy|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ when both $x$ and $y$ are assumed to be real numbers.  Therefore, we have

$$\left|\frac{z+ia}{z-ia}\right|=\sqrt{\frac{x^2+(y+a)^2}{x^2+(y-a)^2}}$$

Can you finish now?

Comment: Your first line holds only if $x$ is real, no? In my case what you are treating like  $x$ is in fact $z$, a  complex number.

Comment: @Chillpadde You're mistaken.  Complex numbers $z$ can always be expressed in the form $x+iy, x, y \in \Bbb R$.  The answer is exactly correct.

Comment: @RobertShore So does the following statement hold? $|z+ia| = \sqrt{x^2 + (y+a)^2}$.

Comment: That was understood from the beginning. I had some other stupid tangle in my head that is cleared up now. I was having trouble seeing why $|x+iy+ia| = \sqrt{x^2 + (y+a)^2}$, but on second look it is glaringly obvious. You've simply taken $i$ common and are left with $|x+i(y+a)|$, from which point the answer is obvious.

Comment: @Chillpadde Yes, you see it now.